# Adding GooglePlaces framework Manually (no PODS)

Tags: swift3, linker, frameworks

I'm trying to add the Google Places API to a blank, new project. I followed the directions on the Getting Started URL. I added all the frameworks and linked all the listed binaries and added -ObjC to the Other Linked Binaries as it says to do. Tried to compile/run with nothing but the added frameworks and -BOOM- 149 Linker errors....

First one says:

> Apple Mach-O Linker Error Group
>
> "_GMSx_GTMSessionFetcherAssertValidSelector", referenced from:

I haven't even written one line of code... Not a good start to a project!!

No - I don't want to use PODs

Comment: Figured it out - I had to add a bunch of other frameworks which I deciphered from the logs. Duh!!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - I had to add a bunch of other frameworks which I deciphered from the logs. Duh!!

[image: Linked Frameworks and Libraries]